# ! LaTeX Error: File `knitr.sty' not found

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit a simple markdown file to a pdf using knitr and R Studio.  The chunks all run fine and I have no problems knitting to an HTML document, but get the following error when trying to knit to a pdf:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `knitr.sty' not found.
```

I have reinstalled tinytex and made sure that the knitr and rmarkdown packages are up to date.  I've looked around and while there are similar issue with other *.sty files, I can't find anything relating to this one.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Can't remember the exact setting but there should be something like "update packages o n the fly" which solves such issues?

Comment: Where is this setting?  In R Studio, Tinytex or Knitr?

Comment: Probably tinytex. Just a checkbox. See this: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex-pkgs.html

Comment: This error should only occur when you use `.Rtex` documents (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250207/knitr-package-error-in-overleaf-latex-error-file-knitr-sty-not-found#comment118884121_67250207), but you said you were knitting Markdown. I can't think of a possible reason why this could occur for Markdown documents. Would you please provide a minimal reprex? And @NelsonGon tinytex won't solve the problem because `knitr.sty` is not from a LaTeX package from CTAN.

Comment: Hi Yihui, thanks for the reply.  As a test, I've cut my file down so it only includes ordinary text and basic Latex code.  Would it help if I sent you the log file?

Comment: Solved this.  Embarrassing error made by me but will post as an answer in case it is somehow instructive: for some reason I had listed several R packages in the 'extra_dependencies' part of the YAML metadata.  Once removed it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this: for some reason I had listed several R packages in the 'extra_dependencies' part of the YAML metadata. Once removed it worked.